# Using wp_enqueue_script on shortcode function handler

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

I have this code

```
function this_is_my_shortcode(){
    wp_register_script('per-pas-belanja-online', plugins_url('js/per-pas-belanja-online.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0.0');
    wp_enqueue_script('per-pas-belanja-online');
    return '<div id="poppedout">Blah</div>';
}
add_shortcode('bubba', 'this_is_my_shortcode');
```

The div is appear on the page, but the script is not. What mistake i have done ?

Comment: as of WordPress 3.3 your code should work just fine

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

> Use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action to call this function, or `admin_enqueue_scripts` to call it on the admin side. Calling it **outside** of an action can lead to troubles.

Comment: To clarify: in order to take effect, a script must be enqueued *before* WordPress actually *prints* those enqueued scripts (which takes place within the `wp_head` hook - which itself includes a long list of actions that take place, including printing of enqueued scripts and styles). Once WordPress is outputting Post content, you are *well* past that point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes everything clear. But, I want to enqueue script only when user use that shortcode. Is there a way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

As @Bainternet pointed out as of 3.3 it should work just fine for js (described by scribu [here](http://scribu.net/wordpress/conditional-script-loading-revisited.html)). For those also wanting to conditionally load css, it's still difficult but these two articles by [beerpla](http://beerpla.net/2010/01/13/wordpress-plugin-development-how-to-include-css-and-javascript-conditionally-and-only-when-needed-by-the-posts/) and one by [iandunn](http://iandunn.name/conditionally-loading-javascript-and-css-in-wordpress-plugins/) should pave the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should enqueue scripts like this:

```
function this_is_my_shortcode(){
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
        wp_register_script('per-pas-belanja-online', plugins_url('js/per-pas-belanja-online.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0.0');
        wp_enqueue_script('per-pas-belanja-online');
    });
    return '<div id="poppedout">Blah</div>';
}
add_shortcode('bubba', 'this_is_my_shortcode');
```